# Why does relative text moved left, cause overflow?

Tags: html, css

I have a `p` tag inside a `div`, and I want to move it left 50px. When I try, it adds a horizontal scroll bar to the page? 
Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/fa9sp8bs/

I do not want to hide the whole scroll bar in css.

Comment: `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: "I do not want to hide the whole scroll bar in css."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really difficult to understand. I assume you're talking about the first `P` tag and also, I assume you need it to be aligned center but moved 50px to left. If I'm right, so modify your code as below, otherwise, please explain more.

```
.title p {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote 500px not 50px, may that be the reason?